# Tablayout animation like whatsapp

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tablayout

I am using `TabLayout` and `SearcView`. How can I do , when click search button to hide tab layout like whatsapp.
I try `setEnabled` method but it can't work properly.
I also used `Visibility`,`setActivated` method.What can I do?I don't know. I must use `setAnimation` method or something else?

MainActivity.java

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    

    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.root_view);
        

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        setUpViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        
    }

    private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(CurrencyFragment.getInstance(),"Tracker"); // `CurrencyFragment.getInstance()` should be in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(ConvertFragment.getInstance(),"Converter"); // `ConvertFragment.getInstance()` should be in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used menu item for search then you have to follow below code:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.search) // set your own id if you have different id from search. 
            {
                tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return true;
            }  

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);            
    }
```

When you finished with search then set tablayout visible.

```
tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these simple steps**

1. In your XML file create Appbar. Inside that create a Constraintlayout and keep it as match parent match parent.
2. Inside that keep your toolbar at the top and below that your tab layout.
3. Now Create the Edittext of search view as WhatsApp and keep it also as Top_to_top of parent and make the view View. Gone.
4. In Activity on click of the search icon

   ```
   toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   searchViewEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   ```